# Rework with my interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have the interface which has 5 methods.

```
 public interface IPhoneAccountTransfer
{
    BalanceInfo[] GetInmateAccountBalance();
    AuthorizationCallConfirmation GetAuthorizeCallResult();
    ChargeAuthorizationConfirmation CommitChargeAuthorization(string authCode);
    ChargeAuthorizationConfirmation CancelBalanceTransfer(string authorizationToken);
    VerifyAuthorizationConfirmation VerifyAuthorization();
}
```

The question is that I have different vendors for Phone Account transfer. Now in my methods the return types are associated with one third party.

For example.

```
public partial class BalanceInfo
{
    private BalanceType typeField;
    private decimal amountField;

    public BalanceType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
         }
      }
```

And:

```
public enum BalanceType
{
     Available,
     Phone,
     Commissary,
     Account,
     Debt,
     Held,
 }
```

Say I want to keep the five methods for the implementation. Can I make the methods generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create you own custom return types:

```
public interface IPhoneAccountTransfer
{
    YourCustomBalanceInfo[] GetInmateAccountBalance();
    YourCustomAuthorizationCallConfirmation GetAuthorizeCallResult();
    YourCustomChargeAuthorizationConfirmation CommitChargeAuthorization(string authCode);
    YourCustomChargeAuthorizationConfirmation CancelBalanceTransfer(string authorizationToken);
    YourCustomVerifyAuthorizationConfirmation VerifyAuthorization();
}
```

And convert the third party response to you own known type.

And here's an implementation example:

```
public YourCustomVerifyAuthorizationConfirmation VerifyAuthorization()
{
    VerifyAuthorizationConfirmation res = DoLogic();
    YourCustomVerifyAuthorizationConfirmation yourWrappedRes = MapResponse(res);
    return yourWrappedRes;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just updated my code, need more help. Say different vendor has different `BalanceInfo`, how to custom my own?

Comment: You use the vendor's types as internal implementations (per vendor) but the output has to be cross vendor. Lets say you need to ask for a loan, you call your banker and wait for a response. The banker will talk with multiple people but you shouldn't care about that. All you need is the bankers response.

Answer (score 0):

Can I make the methods generic?

Sure - but then would you want *each* return type to be generic?  If so then you'd have to have *five* generic parameters.  Which would give you compile-time safety but would add a lot of complexity to the usage.

There's a lot of details to be inferred, but it sounds like you have a few options:

1. Use the current return types you have now as base classes and return vendor-specific classes.

   - How similar are the different vendors's types?  Do they have many properties in common and just have a few variances?
   - One downside is you'd have to cast the return type in the client to use its non-standard properties
2. Use a "universal" return type that covers all known vendors, and only populate the fields relevant for that particualar vendor

   - The main benefit here is you don't have to cast when you use the vendor-specific fields
3. Use different methods for each vendor

   - That may mean that you can't use one interface (at least not for those methods) but with different return types one interface may not be the right solution anyways